# Is there any different in Screen displaying character between smart phone and non-smart phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, ascii, character

I try to send some characters and ASCII characters in SMS. This what I found.
Smartphone send to smart phone like WP7, the characters are displayed correctly and fit the screen. But When use smart phone send the same to Non-Smart phone. The problems are

1. Characters are far apart !
2. Characters image wont fit into the screen even though fit in smart phone

here the XAML : the image of a cat in Ascii

```
<TextBlock Height="104" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="31,229,0,0" Name="txtBlkCat" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172" TextWrapping="Wrap">
          &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;(),,,,,,() <lineBreak/>
          &#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;( ^ _ ^ ) <lineBreak/>
          &#160;&#160;( ,, )&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;( ,, ) <lineBreak/>
</TextBlock>
```

I believe LineBreak and Space are translated correctly. can someone help to explain why this is happening?

Comment: I've tried to tidy up your code (xaml) sample. Can you check that it displays correctly.

Comment: @Matt Lacey: Thank. except Each line should end with  <lineBreak/> inside TextBlock.

Comment: I've made that change. Have a look at what I've done (go to edit the question) so you can see how to create this formatting in future. See also http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things:

How do you define "smart phone" and "non-smart phone"? There are no hard and fast definitions and even within these categories there can be massive variations in capabilities and functionality.

Character encodings can be interpreted differently by differetn carriers and networks that an SMS message is sent through. Anything other than baisc ASCII characters can end up being represented differently.

What do you think `160` will be encoded as? I think it'll be a lower case letter a with an acute accent. (á). I'm guessing that's not what you want.

If trying to display ASCII art you should make sure you are using a typeface with mono-type spacing (fixed width) otherwise things may not display as you intend.

Comment: What I need to do to send ASCII art for Windows Phone 7? In Silverlight for Wp7, I need to hard code the ASCII and characters.for space, I use &#160, end of line use <lIneBreak/>. This will be re-converted by the OS before sending it out. Thanks